# How to separate two divs vertically from each other?

Tags: html, css

While I was making a div for the navigation bar, I also thought of making a second div that represents the left side of the website, with the class "left".

```css
#nav {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}




.left {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="left"></div>
```

My question is: how could I separate the "navigation bar" div from the "left" div?

Comment: @Ryan I have never heard of this idea before. What else would you recommend for CSS that is only to be used once?

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the information, I will need to look into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#nav {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}




.left {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Do you mean like this, with a simple `<br>`?

```css
#nav {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: green;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: yellow;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: black;
}

.left {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Or alternatively, with `margin-top`?

Comment: Thanks, both of them helped me!

Comment: @Alien I am glad to help. :)